# In Thymeleaf with multiple actions and multiple forms are possible?

Tags: forms, spring, scala, thymeleaf

Hi i am new in thymeleaf + spring  and i start learn it.
and wanted to **integrate** these **2 form** in **one page** .

that means **now 2  forms are in 2 different pages** and the **th:action are different** ..

here i want these **2 forms  work in one page**

i tried that with a page with 2 forms and 2 actions but that caught error..

**Create Standard Code**

```
<form action="#" th:action="@{/saveStandard.html}" th:object="${standard}">
        <table>
            <h1>Create Standard</h1>
        <tr>
        <td>Standard Name:</td>
        <td><input type="text" placeholder="Enter Standard Name" required="required"   
            th:field="*{standardName}"/></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
        <td><input type="submit" value="Create" name="save" /></td>
        </tr>
        </table>
</form>
```

**Create Division Code**

```
<form action="#" th:action="@{/saveDivision.html}"
         th:object="${division}">
             <table>
         <td>Division Name:</td>
             <tr>
         <td><input type="text" placeholder="Enter Division Name" required="required"
         th:field="*{divisionName}" /> 
             </td>
             </tr>
         <td><input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Create"
         name="save" /></td>
</table>
</form>
```

these are controllers..

```
    @RequestMapping(value = Array("/saveStandard.html"), params = Array({ "save" }))
     def saveStandard(standard: Standard): String = {
      standard.setCreatedDate(new java.sql.Date(new java.util.Date().getTime))
      standardService.addStandard(standard)
      "redirect:/school/CreateStandard.html"
      }

  @RequestMapping(value = Array("/saveDivision.html"), params = Array({ "save" }))
   def saveDivision(division: Division): String = {
      division.setCreatedDate(new java.sql.Date(new java.util.Date().getTime))
      divisionService.addDivision(division)
      "redirect:/school/CreateDivision.html"
      }
```

if you knew about this question please share your answer here..

and  Thanks...

Comment: And whats the error? Multiple forms are certainly possible since each form is submitted on itself with a submit button in these forms.

Comment: @MartinFrey sorry . i think it's because of multiple th:actions that returns multiple redirects.. is there any possibility's for that

Comment: If you submit one form this redirect will happen and you should reach the new page. The question is what do you want to achieve? Have two forms and submit them together? Have two form submit them each alone and replace parts of the page with the result? If there is an error. Whats the error / exception?

Comment: i think he wants to load the 2 forms data in one page and perform 2 actions then redirect to another page.... but where is exception occured

Answer (score 1):

Hi It is posible here a example

HTML Example

```
    <section id="registration" class="section">
        <div class="container tagline">
            <em>Register User</em><br />
            <form method="post" th:action="@{/user/register}" th:object="${newUser}">
                <div>
                    <label for="givenName">Id</label>
                    <input id="id" placeholder="Enter Id"  type="text" th:field="*{id}" />
                    <p th:if="${#fields.hasErrors('id')}" th:text="${#strings.listJoin(#fields.errors('id'), ', ')}">
                    </p> 
                </div>
                <div>
                    <label for="givenName">Name</label>
                    <input id="name" placeholder="Enter Name"  type="text" th:field="*{name}" />
                    <p th:if="${#fields.hasErrors('name')}"
                        th:text="${#strings.listJoin(#fields.errors('name'), ', ')}"></p>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <label for="email">Email</label>
                    <input id="email" placeholder="Enter the Email"  type="text" th:field="*{email}" />
                    <p th:if="${#fields.hasErrors('email')}"
                        th:text="${#strings.listJoin(#fields.errors('email'), ', ')}"></p>
                </div>
                <button type="submit">Create user</button>
            </form>

        </div>
    </section>

<div>
<form method="get" th:action="@{/user/searchById}" th:object="${searchUser}">
         <input id="id"  placeholder="Search by id"  type="text"  th:field="*{id}" size="10" >
         <button type="submit" >search</button> 

</form>

<form method="get" th:action="@{/user/searchByName}" th:object="${searchUser}">
         <input id="id"  placeholder="Search by Name"  type="text"  th:field="*{name}" size="10" >
         <button type="submit" >search</button> 

</form>

<form method="get" th:action="@{/user/searchByEmail}" th:object="${searchUser}">
         <input id="id"  placeholder="Search by Email"  type="text"  th:field="*{email}" size="10" >
         <button type="submit" >search</button> 
</form>

</div>
```

Spring

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/user")
public class User {

    BookingFacadeUserImp userService = new BookingFacadeUserImp();

    @GetMapping()
    public ModelAndView init() {
        return getModelView().addObject("users", getUsersByName("", 100, 0));
    }

    @PostMapping("/register")
    public ModelAndView saveUser(@Valid @ModelAttribute("newUser") UserDTO user, BindingResult result)
            throws NumberFormatException, ParseException {

        System.out.println("Register: " + user);
        userService.createUser(user);
        return getModelView().addObject("users", getUsersByName("", 100, 0));
    }

    @GetMapping("/delete/{id}")
    public ModelAndView delete(@PathVariable long id) {
        userService.deleteUser(id);
        return init();
    }

    @PostMapping("/update")
    public ModelAndView updateUser(@ModelAttribute("updateUser") UserDTO user) {
        userService.updateUser(user);
        return init();
    }

    @GetMapping("/searchById")
    public ModelAndView searchById(@ModelAttribute("searchUser") UserDTO user) {

        if (user.getId() > 0)
            return getModelView().addObject("users", getUsersById(user.getId()));
        else
            return init();
    }

    @GetMapping("/searchByName")
    public ModelAndView searchByName(@ModelAttribute("searchUser") UserDTO user) {
        if (!user.getName().equals(""))
            return getModelView().addObject("users", getUsersByName(user.getName(),100,0));
        else
            return init();
    }
    
    public ModelAndView getModelView() {
        ModelAndView model = new ModelAndView("user");
        model.addObject("newUser", new UserDTO());
        model.addObject("searchUser", new UserDTO());
        return model;
    }

    public List<UserDTO> getUsersById(long id) {

        List<UserDTO> list = new ArrayList<UserDTO>();
        list.add((UserDTO) userService.getUserById(id));
        return list;
    }

    public List<com.example.demo.task1.model.User> getUsersByName(String name, int pageSiza, int pageNum) {
        return userService.getUsersByName(name, pageSiza, pageNum);
    }

    public List<com.example.demo.task1.model.User> getUsersByEmail(String email) {
        return (List<com.example.demo.task1.model.User>) userService.getUserByEmail(email);
    }
}
```